# Failed to update the state using BlockBuilder() and TextField()'s onChanged property. [Flutter_Bloc]

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I am trying to do a simple mockup of form validation, and so far I was not able to update my State under the BlocBuilder() using the TextField()'s onChanged property.

Here's my BlocProvider()

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Log me in',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: BlocProvider<LoginBloc>(
          create: (context) => LoginBloc(),
          child: LoginScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the main file that needs to be updated on input changes.
The '$snapshot' supposed to yields the what's coming from the LoginBloc depending on its' current state, but looks like it doesn't rebuild itself onChanged online StreamBuilder()

```dart
lass LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final LoginBloc bloc = BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context);
    return BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, String>(
        bloc: LoginBloc(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                // emailField(bloc),
                TextField(
                  onChanged: (_) => bloc.add(LoginEvent.username),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'example@email.com',
                    labelText: 'Email Address',
                    errorText: '$snapshot',
                  ),
                ),
                // passwordField(bloc),
                TextField(
                  onChanged: (_) => bloc.add(LoginEvent.password),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Password',
                    labelText: 'Password',
                    errorText: '$snapshot',
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 25,
                ),
                // submitButton(),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

Here's my LoginBloc()

```dart
class LoginBloc extends Bloc<LoginEvent, String> {
  get initialState => '';

  Stream<String> mapEventToState(LoginEvent event) async* {
    switch (event) {
      case LoginEvent.username:
        if (state.contains('@')) {
          yield 'Approved';
        } else {
          yield 'Please retry';
        }
        break;
      case LoginEvent.password:
        if (state.length > 3) {
          yield 'Nice password';
        }
        yield "Please retry";
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different instances of `LoginBloc` in your app. The one created and passed by the `BlocProvider` and the second which you have created inside the `BlocBuilder`.

The problem is that you are adding events into the `BlocProvider's` bloc and the `BlocBuilder` is listening to the another one.

To fix this you can do like this

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final LoginBloc bloc = BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context);
  return BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, String>(
    bloc: bloc,      // Pass the above bloc instance 
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      // rest as it is
    }
  )
}
```

**Bonus:-** You can skip the `bloc: bloc` as it is an optional argument and if not provided it finds automatically from the tree using BlocProvider

You also need to manage state differently otherwise typing in one of the field will show error in both of them

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in this line:

```dart
final LoginBloc bloc = BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context);
```

You're accessing the bloc in wrong context. Remove that line and use `BlocProvider` directly when you want to access `LoginBloc`:

```dart
onChanged: (_) => BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context).add(LoginEvent.username),
```